# flask create_app and setUp unittest

Tags: database, unit-testing, flask

So I have setted up my flask in this way:

```
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../designs/UI', template_folder='../designs/UI', instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object(app_config[config_name])
    app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_message = "You must be logged in to access this page."
    login_manager.login_view = "auth.login_page"

    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    from app import models

    from .api import blueprint as api_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')

    @app.route('/')
    def homepage():
        return redirect('/api/v1.0')

    return app
```

And my unittest setup:

```
def setUp(self):
    """setup test variables"""
    self.app = create_app(config_name="testing")
    self.client = self.app.test_client

    # binds the app with the current context
    with self.app.app_context():
        #create all tables
        db.session.close()
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
```

When I import my models into the test file and try to access anything from the database I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no applicationbound to current context

Is there any better way to set up the entire thing so that it may work?

Comment: Did you try to push context? ```ctx = app.app_context() ctx.push()```

Comment: No, where do I do that?

Comment: instead `with self.app.app_context()` -> `ctx  =  self.app.app_context() ctx.push()`

Comment: It's working, although my tests are failing, is that's all I need to do? Or is there something else I need to do also? And please explain why its working in non-technical language.

Comment: Its working because you pushed `app context` manually. Why tests are failing? Which reason?

Comment: It's working, the tests are failing because of my own fault. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I decided to explain the problem(and solution) in detail.

**1) Why your way doesn't work?**
Because you trying to push `app context` using [Context Manager](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Context_Managers). What does it mean? `current context` will be available only inside `with` block. You bind `context` and he available only in `setUp`, but not in tests. `app` will works without `context` when `setUp()` is finished. Let's look at this example:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

class TestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        with app.app_context():
            # current_app is available(you will see <Flask 'app'> in terminal)
            print current_app
        # out of context manager - RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
        print current_app

    def test_example(self):
        pass
```

Run test. You'll be see Flask 'app' + exception. The error will disappear if you remove last print(out of `with` block).

**2) How to fix the problem?**
You can bind `app context` without Context Manager.

```
class TestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        ctx = app.app_context()
        ctx.push()
        # after this you can use current_app
        print current_app

    def test_example(self):
        # available because we pushed context in setUp()
        print current_app
```

Run test:

```
<Flask 'app'> # from setUp()
<Flask 'app'> # from test_example
```

So, let's sum up. `current_app` is available ONLY 'inside' Context Manager. But you can bind context without Context Manager.

I hope that I have explained the details and answered your questions.