# How to unittest a function that use app.logger of Flask

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging, flask, pytest

For sure I'm missing something in Flask and unit test integration (or logger configuration maybe)

But when I'm trying to unittest some class methods that have some app.logger I'm having troubles with `RuntimeError: working outside of the application context`

So a practical example:

utils.py

```
import boto3
from flask import current_app as app

class CustomError(BaseException):
    type = "boto"

class BotoManager:
    def upload_to_s3(self, file):
        try:
            # do something that can trigger a boto3 error
        except boto3.exceptions.Boto3Error as e:
            app.logger.error(e)
            raise CustomError()
```

test_utils.py

```
import pytest

from utils.py import CustomError, BotoManager

def test_s3_manager_trigger_error():
    boto_manager = BotoManager()
    with pytest.raises(CustomError):
        boto_manager.upload_to_s3('file.txt')  # file doesn't exist so trigger error
```

So the thing is that when I run it show me the error:
`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Becuase the app is not created and I'm not working with the app, so have sense.

So I only see two possible solutions (spoiler I don't like any of them):

- Don't log anything with app.logger outside of the views (I think I can use the python logging system, but this is not the desired behaviour)
- Don't unittest the parts that use app.logger

Did someone face this problem already? How did you solve it? Any other possible solution?

Comment: You can just [send context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353929/flask-create-app-and-setup-unittest) manually before tests.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Thanks! it works perfectly!

Comment: I think you would have this question with testing any part flask project, not just the logging functionality. I use a [base class](https://github.com/mini-kep/db/blob/65e396b55cfc507952b827e142f2221f31356759/tests/test_basic.py#L27-L82) that I inherit test from for these purposes.